# A Git of Gits - Including .git sub-directories in a repository

Tags: git, backup, snapshot

I'd like to include `.git` subdirectories in a repository, but git seems to have some built-in rule that makes them be ignored or blocks their inclusion:

For example, with a directory structure like this:

```
/a
    /.git
        a-git-1.txt
/b
    /b1
        /.git
            b-b1-git-1.txt
```

That you could create with this:

```
mkdir "a/.git"
echo file in a/.git > a/.git/a-git-1.txt
mkdir "b/1/.git"
echo file in b/1/.git > b/1/.git/b-b1-git.txt
```

If I do:

```
git init
git add .
git status
```

git status will tell me that there's nothing to commit; no file has been added.

If I try to add the files explicitly:

```
git add a/.git/a-git-1.txt
git add b/1/.git/b-b1-git.txt
```

I'm even given an error:

```
error: Invalid path 'a/.git/a-git-1.txt'
error: unable to add a/.git/a-git-1.txt to index
fatal: adding files failed

error: Invalid path 'b/1/.git/b-b1-git.txt'
error: unable to add b/1/.git/b-b1-git.txt to index
fatal: adding files failed
```

And of course git status will still tell me that no file has been added.

I'm using msysgit 1.9.5.

---

Actually I found out that the doc technical/index-format explicitly says:

> The special path components ".", ".." and ".git" (without quotes) are disallowed

so maybe this is intended and there's no workaround.

But I'm still not sure.

So what I'd like to know is: **Do you know of a way to add these `.git` directories to a repository?**

---

By the way, is somebody aware if this limitation is intentional, or maybe they just wanted to avoid the real `.git` repository but they included the subdirectories by mistake?

---

Why would I want this? It would be useful to easily store snapshots of the repository.

Why would I want to store snapshots? Doing that (with simple directory copies) often saved me from git's peculiarities, actual bugs or just mistakes of mine, from which would have been very hard if not impossible to recover with hunts in the reflogs or stuff like that. A look to older snapshots allowed me to understand what happened or find lost branches quite quickly.

To make the snapshots I currently do plain directory copies and zip them all at the end of the project (at some point I will probably start deleting them), but I thought that using a git repository could be more convenient, allowing me to take more snapshots without using a lot of disk space during the project.

---

Thanks for reading all this and for any help that you'll want to provide

Comment: is it important to add the `.git` folder to itself? You can init a new repo inside the `.git` folder and to manage it as a different repo. Does it make sense for you?

Comment: @YuriG. That's one I hadn't thought of!
Yes it works, it can be a workaround.

Actually I'd like to store the working directory along with the repository, but that could be worked out.

Indeed another workaround that seems to work is to simply rename the .git directory. I'll take this route if nothing better comes out, but having to rename back and forth or maybe to always specify --git-dir is a little inconvenient, so I hope a more straightforward way comes up.

Comment: You could make an alias: `alias g='git --git-dir=/path-to-fake-git-dir'`